# How to avoid comparing duplicate strings in a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of a hundred or so strings and each string is compared with one another in 2 for loops, here is a very basic overview of code:

```
string_list = ["PII", "AZO", "CVCO", "MOD"]

for x in string_list:
    for y in string_list:
        if x != y:
            print (x, y)
```

Which prints:

```
PII AZO
PII CVCO
PII MOD
AZO PII
AZO CVCO
AZO MOD
CVCO PII
CVCO AZO
CVCO MOD
MOD PII
MOD AZO
MOD CVCO
```

As you can see, a lot of the strings are compared twice (PII - AZO and AZO - PII, etc.)

I've been trying to figure out how to avoid this problem using 2 count variables but I am scratching my head, there must be an easier/pythonic way of doing this so there are no overlapping string comparisons, does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Python 3, thanks.

EDIT:

Expected result:

```
PII AZO
PII CVCO
PII MOD
AZO CVCO
AZO MOD
CVCO MOD
```

Comment: What's the expected result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> string_list = ["PII", "AZO", "CVCO", "MOD"]
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> for a, b in combinations(string_list, 2):
...     print(a, b)
... 
PII AZO
PII CVCO
PII MOD
AZO CVCO
AZO MOD
CVCO MOD
```

Your version generated [permutations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) instead.

Comment: Just remember that combinations will produce a generator, and you can only loop through a generator once. If you need the combos more than once use something like combos = list(combinations(string_list, 2))

Comment: Minor nitpick: the OP's version isn't equivalent to `itertools.permutations()`.  If the list contains repeated items, the former wouldn't generate any `(x, x)` results, while the latter would.

Answer (score 2):

The way you could do this by hand is by iterating over the second list, starting after the index of the first list:

```
import itertools

for i, x in enumerate(string_list):
    for y in itertools.islice(string_list, i + 1, None)
        # if you don't have duplicates, this next check isn't necessary
        if x != y:
            print(x, y)
```

[`itertools.islice(list, start, stop)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is like `list[start:stop]`, but doesn't make a copy. Thanks to commenters who pointed that out.

Comment: `itertools.islice(string_list,i, None)`.

Comment: `itertools.islice()` would let you avoid a copy. :-)

Comment: Thanks for explaining how it works, I choose the other answer only out of simplicity.

Comment: @Goose That's generally a good plan -- use the standard library as much as you can. I just wanted to explain how to do it without that in case you needed to for some reason (or just wanted to know how it worked).